# Minecraft /execute as a player if they are alive

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have an `/execute` command in a repeating command block, such as:

> execute @a ~ ~ ~ say hi

This makes every player say hi every tick, even if they are dead and at the 'Respawn?' screen.
How would I make the `/execute` only happen if the player is alive?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done with the `health` scoreboard. Create an objective with:

> /scoreboard objectives create h health

This creates an objective `h`, which tracks player's health (by number of half-hearts).
Change your command to:

> execute @a[score_h_min=1] ~ ~ ~ say hi

This only triggers if the player has at least a half-heart (they're alive).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a selector that does not have the ability to target dead players, such as `@e` (with `type=Player` to ensure player-based targeting):

```
/execute @e[type=Player] ~ ~ ~ say hi
```